# SLT Error: Replication not successfull: The migration object has been deleted and must be recreated

Tags: slt

We try to build an SLT (SAP Landscape Transformation) Configuration which replicates one Table "new3_asdf" and one view on top of this table: new3_asdf_view_id.

So in transaction LTRS I added the view to the table:

[image: LTRS Screenshot: add view to table]

In LTRC I added the table new3_asdf to replication. Even though there is no 'X' in column failed the replication does not work :((

The 'View Errors' Button reveals the Error / Cause:

Migration object Z_NEW3_ASDF_035 has been deleted due to changes in table definition

[image]

How can I recreate it according to the Help Text:

[image]

Source and destination databases are DB2 10.5

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error when you change the table structure in LTRS while the job is replicating in LTRC.  It appears to drop the target table, making your replication job fail because you have no target.  You have to have all your LTRS table config in place before LTRC or this message can happen.